# Visual Studio 2013 XSLT Profile

Tags: xml, xslt, visual-studio-2013, profile, profiler

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Premium and wanted to profile my XSLT, but the button is greyed out? I can debug it, do I need another version to profile it, Visual Studio Ultimate?
Microsoft only has a documentation for 2010 and 2012 [XSLT Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456801%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)
But I have the button in my environment:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page on [XSLT Profiler Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473446.aspx) is a page for Visual Studio 2013, saying the following:

> The XSLT Profiler is only available with the Microsoft Visual Studio Team System with Profiling Tools installed.

Which seems to me that you are out of luck. I happen to have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and that has an available profiler, and I doubt much has changed, so if you can downgrade (and happen to have a Premium edition on the shelf):

[image: Printscreen of tools in VS2012 Premium]

Though a cheaper option might be to go for [oXygen](https://www.oxygenxml.com) or [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com), both come with a profiling option, the latter [claiming to be processor independent](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xslt-profiler.html). I myself use oXygen a lot with our own [Exselt XSLT 3.0](http://exselt.net) processor (Microsoft is still in the 1990s with support for XSLT 1.0 only), but that doesn't yet come with a profiler. However I believe [Saxon](http://saxonica.com), also XSLT 3.0, has a [simple profiler tool](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.html).

Comment: Thank you!
So Microsoft Visual Studio Team Systems with Profiling Tools is only available in the Ultimate Edition?
I use Oxygen, but the problem is I have some msxsl functions with C# code in my xslt and oxygen can´t transform it. So I will take a look at Stylus Studio.